# Hiding the nav-bar, while opening in the new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a web page where I'll display a table inside a div. I've a button called full view. When I click that button, only that div should be displayed in a new window. All others should be hidden. Only the div and the table inside it should be displayed. This is how I tried to display in the new window:

```
    <?php include("include-this/nav-bar.php"); ?>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="dash_div">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Final
            <div id="contract_toolbar" name="contract_toolbar" class="btn-group pull-right">
                <button id="full_view" name="full_view" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="window.open('#dash_div', '_blank')">


Full View
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="table_dashboard" class="table table-striped table-bordered hide">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Total number</th>
                        <th>Total Value</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

            var input_report = jQuery("#input_report").val();
            //var table_id = "#table_report_" + input_report;
            alert(input_report);
            jQuery("#table_dashboard").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
            jQuery("#table_dashboard").DataTable( {
                dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'Bftri>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>",
                paging: false,
                ajax: "db.php?report=" + input_report,
            });
        });
```

I've included the nav-bar in the first line. When I click the full view button, the div opens in a new window along with the nav-bar. But, I don't want that. I want to display only the div. I don't know what should I do to hide that nav-bar. Can someone tell me how to hide that when the div is opened in a new window?

Comment: paste more code where we can see how are you opening that new window. If you put some name to the new window, you can reference to elements inside that window as well

Comment: I'm opening the window in the onclick function of the button. Check the onclick function of the button. I've shown it there.

Comment: where can I check the onclick function? it was not provided in pasted code

Comment: <button id="dashboard_full_view" name="dashboard_full_view" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="window.open('#dash_div', '_blank')">

Answer (score 1):

change `onclick="window.open('#dash_div', '_blank')"` to `onclick="openWindow('#dash_div');"`
and add this function to your JS:

```
function openWindow(hash) {
    var openedWindow = window.open(hash, '_blank');
    openedWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('panel-heading')[0].style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: Sorry dude, the nav-bar is still displayed. It's not hiding.

Comment: you should change somehow this line:
openedWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('panel-heading')[0].style.display='none';
openedWindow.document is the DOM of everything in opened window